# Firebase Realtime Array count mismatch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS swift app using Firebase realtime database. If I use the app normally so far I cannot find any issue. However, I want to anticipate edge cases.

I am trying to stress test my app before I push the update, and one way I am doing it is quickly going back and forth from a VC with a tableView to the next VC which is a detail VC. If I do it several times eventually the tableview will show lots of duplicate data.

I have tested my app by having a tableview open on my simulator and going into my Firebase Console and manually changing a value and instantly on the device the string changes.

So I am confused as to why my tableview would show an incorrect amount of children if it is constantly checking what the value should be.

```
// MARK: Firebase Methods

func checkIfDataExits() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cardArray.removeAll()
         self.ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChild("cards") {
                self.pullAllUsersCards()
            } else {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}



func pullAllUsersCards() {
    cardArray.removeAll()
    let userRef = ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("cards")
    userRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for userscard in snapshot.children {
            let cardID = (userscard as AnyObject).key as String
            let cardRef = self.ref.child("cards").child(cardID)
            cardRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (cardSnapShot) in
                let cardSnap = cardSnapShot as DataSnapshot
                let cardDict = cardSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let cardNickname = cardDict["nickname"]
                let cardType = cardDict["type"]
                let cardStatus = cardDict["cardStatus"]
                self.cardNicknameToTransfer = cardNickname as! String
                self.cardtypeToTransfer = cardType as! String
                let aCard = CardClass()
                aCard.cardID = cardID
                aCard.nickname = cardNickname as! String
                aCard.type = cardType as! String
                aCard.cStatus = cardStatus as! Bool
                self.cardArray.append(aCard)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use a firebase method on the numberOfItemsInSection or something ?

Comment: Not sure we are seeing enough code. Things like viewDid/WillAppear would be helpful as would the table methods and any setter/getter properties on the array containing the table data. Typically when there are issues with duplicate data in a table, it's because the table's data array is not getting cleared before being reloaded. As you are going back and forth between two different views, anything in viewWillAppear, for example, will be called each time you switch back to the table view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got help and changed my code drastically, so now it works

```
func checkIfDataExits() {
    self.ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild("services") {
            self.pullCardData()
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}


func pullCardData() {
    let cardRef = self.ref.child("cards")
    cardRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for cards in snapshot.children {
            let allCardIDs = (cards as AnyObject).key as String
            if allCardIDs == self.cardID {
                if let childId = self.cardID {
                    let thisCardLocation = cardRef.child(childId)
                    thisCardLocation.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        let thisCardDetails = snapshot as DataSnapshot
                        if let cardDict = thisCardDetails.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            self.selectedCard?.cardID = thisCardDetails.key
                            self.selectedCard?.nickname = cardDict["nickname"] as? String ?? ""
                            self.selectedCard?.type = cardDict["type"] as? String ?? ""
                            self.pullServicesForCard()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

func pullServicesForCard() {
    if let theId = self.cardID {
        let thisCardServices = self.ref.child("cards").child(theId).child("services")
        thisCardServices.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (serviceSnap) in
            if self.serviceArray.count != Int(serviceSnap.childrenCount) {
                self.serviceArray.removeAll()
                self.fetchAndAddAllServices(serviceSnap: serviceSnap, index: 0, completion: { (success) in
                    if success {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

func fetchAndAddAllServices(serviceSnap: DataSnapshot, index: Int, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    if serviceSnap.hasChildren() {
        if index < serviceSnap.children.allObjects.count {
            let serviceChild = serviceSnap.children.allObjects[index]
            let serviceID = (serviceChild as AnyObject).key as String

            let thisServiceLocationInServiceNode = self.ref.child("services").child(serviceID)

            thisServiceLocationInServiceNode.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (thisSnap) in
                let serv = thisSnap as DataSnapshot

                if let serviceDict = serv.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    let aService = ServiceClass(serviceDict: serviceDict)
                    self.serviceCurrent = serviceDict["serviceStatus"] as? Bool
                    self.serviceName = serviceDict["serviceName"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.serviceURL = serviceDict["serviceURL"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.serviceFixedBool = serviceDict["serviceFixed"] as? Bool
                    self.serviceFixedAmount = serviceDict["serviceAmount"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.attentionInt = serviceDict["attentionInt"] as? Int

                    self.totalArr.append((serviceDict["serviceAmount"] as? String)!)
                    //                        self.doubleArray = self.totalArr.flatMap{ Double($0) }
                    //                        let arraySum = self.doubleArray.reduce(0, +)
                    //                        self.title = self.selectedCard?.nickname ?? ""

                    //                        if let titleName = self.selectedCard?.nickname {
                    //                            self.title = "\(titleName): \(arraySum)"
                    //                        }

                    aService.serviceID = serviceID
                    if serviceDict["serviceStatus"] as? Bool == true {
                        self.selectedCard?.cStatus = true
                    } else {
                        self.selectedCard?.cStatus = false
                    }



                    if !self.serviceArray.contains(where: { (service) -> Bool in
                        return service.serviceID == aService.serviceID
                    }) {
                        self.serviceArray.append(aService)

                        self.serviceArray.sort {$1.serviceAttention < $0.serviceAttention}

                    }
                }
                self.fetchAndAddAllServices(serviceSnap: serviceSnap, index: index + 1, completion: completion)
            })

        }
        else {
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    else {
        completion(false)
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks good, I'd recommend using some guard statements here. Usually something i do when i have a lot of if-elses (im visual that way, helps playing with unwrapped vars imo).

Comment: @murphguy yea I have a lot of things I need to get better at ...guard is one of them